# How to freeze UI rendering in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app with a very simple user/password authentication:

```
server <- function(input, output) {  
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
  library(V8)
  library(shinyjs)
  hide("sidebar")
  hide("mainPanel")

  credentials <- data.frame(username = c("user1", "user2"), 
                            password = c("password1", "password2"),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$login, {
    # Check if the entered credentials match the stored credentials
    user_data <- credentials[credentials$username == input$username & 
                               credentials$password == input$password,]
    if (nrow(user_data) > 0) {
      # Show the app UI and hide the login inputs
      hide("username")
      hide("password")
      hide("login")
      show("sidebar")
      show("mainPanel")
    } else {
      # Show an error message if the credentials are incorrect
      shinyjs::alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again.")
    }
  })
  
  
}

library(V8)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("username", "Username"),
  passwordInput("password", "Password"),
  actionButton("login", "Log in"),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Inputs: Select variables to plot
    div(id="sidebar",sidebarPanel(
      dateInput(
        inputId = "corte",
        label = "Data as of:",
        value = NULL,
        min = NULL,
        max = NULL,
        format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startview = "month",
        weekstart = 0,
        language = "en",
        width = NULL,
        autoclose = TRUE,
        datesdisabled = NULL,
        daysofweekdisabled = NULL
      ))),
    
    # Output: Show scatterplot
    div(id = "mainPanel",mainPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "reporte",
        label = "Report",
        choices = c("A", "B"),
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = FALSE,
        selectize = TRUE,
        width = NULL,
        size = NULL
      )
      
    )
    )
  
  )
  
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you run the code, you'll notice that when the app is opened, the UI hidden behind the user/password shows up for a split second, and then disappears after the "hide()" functions are executed

How can I stop the mainPanel and sidebar from rendering before the user authenticates with the user/password?

Comment: Please see `shinyjs::hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you add the class `invisible` in the `div()` container of the UI you want to hide, it will be invisible by default eliminating the issue

To make it back visible, you can use the function `shinyjs::removeClass()` to eliminate the "invisible" class. Here is the modified working code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {  
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
  library(V8)
  library(shinyjs)
  hide("sidebar")
  hide("mainPanel")

  credentials <- data.frame(username = c("user1", "user2"), 
                            password = c("password1", "password2"),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$login, {
    # Check if the entered credentials match the stored credentials
    user_data <- credentials[credentials$username == input$username & 
                               credentials$password == input$password,]
    if (nrow(user_data) > 0) {
      # Show the app UI and hide the login inputs
      hide("username")
      hide("password")
      hide("login")
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = ".invisible", class = "invisible")
      show("sidebar")
      show("mainPanel")
    } else {
      # Show an error message if the credentials are incorrect
      shinyjs::alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again.")
    }
  })
  
  
}

library(V8)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("username", "Username"),
  passwordInput("password", "Password"),
  actionButton("login", "Log in"),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Inputs: Select variables to plot
    div(id="sidebar",sidebarPanel(
      dateInput(
        inputId = "corte",
        label = "Data as of:",
        value = NULL,
        min = NULL,
        max = NULL,
        format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startview = "month",
        weekstart = 0,
        language = "en",
        width = NULL,
        autoclose = TRUE,
        datesdisabled = NULL,
        daysofweekdisabled = NULL
      )
      
      ), class = "invisible"),
    
    # Output: Show scatterplot
    div(id = "mainPanel",mainPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "reporte",
        label = "Report",
        choices = c("A", "B"),
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = FALSE,
        selectize = TRUE,
        width = NULL,
        size = NULL
      )
      
    ), class = "invisible"
    )
  
  )
  
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```